# XSLT / XML - Cannot read read attribute of an element

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have xml that looks like this:

```
<Context IsFollowA="0" IsFollowB="1">
    <Info>
        <Name>Rob</Name>
        ...
    </Info>
</Context>
```

In my xslt, I have these statements:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat('x=[', //Context/Info/Name, ']')" /><br/>
<xsl:value-of select="concat('y=[', //Context/@IsFollowA, ']')" /><br/>
<xsl:value-of select="concat('z=[', //Context/@IsFollowB, ']')" /><br/>
```

And my output is:

```
x=[Rob]
y=[]
z=[]
```

I have tried several different paths with no luck.  I just can't get the values set properly.  Am I doing something ridiculous?  I'm not an expert at xslt so chances are that it's something simple that I am missing.  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Should be fine. http://www.xmlplayground.com/GyKDk4

Comment: What processor are you using? Also, what is the context of your `xsl:value-of`'s (can you post the whole template?)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

False alarm... the xml I was looking at was being altered by another service (and the attributes stripped out) before I received it.  Sorry to mislead.

Answer (score 0):

Though it is not clear from the input provided by you, one possible problem might be that: 
There are multiple Context elements , 
One of them might be having attributes as follows:

```
IsFollowA="" IsFollowB=""
```

Then as your XPATH uses // we have no guarantee that the all three lines are referring to the same element.

You can try:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//Context"> 
 <xsl:value-of select="concat('x=[', ./Info/Name, ']')" /><br/> 
 <xsl:value-of select="concat('y=[', ./@IsFollowA, ']')" /><br/> 
 <xsl:value-of select="concat('z=[', ./@IsFollowB, ']')" /><br/> 
</xsl:for-each>
```